# LTC3780 voltage/current limit indicator

Tags: power-supply, current-limiting, indicator

I recently bought an LTC3780 circuit from China to build a variable power supply.
I would also like to have voltage/current limit LED indicator there but every tutorial I found on the internet described the solution using different circuit than mine.

My question is: would it be possible to build such indicators when I am using LTC3780 and if so how complex would be that task?

Thank you for your answers.

P.S.: any hints how to proceed with that will be appreciate

Comment: Show the schematic of the device else it's a dead question.

Comment: Voltage indicator is a voltmeter in parallel and current indicator is an amp meter in series, so, yes, it is possible. Your question is still a bit too broad. Addressing specific problems after your project starts is a better format for this website. Also providing URLs/datasheets of the stuff you are talking about is not only helpful but shows some effort of your part.

Comment: I am following [this](http://www.instructables.com/id/Build-your-own-Variable-Lab-Bench-Power-Supply/) tutorial. I just want to add two LEDs. One LED will light up when my power supply will limit current, otherwise the second LED will light up. I am not sure if I am expressing myself clear enough.

Comment: Author of [this](http://www.instructables.com/id/DIY-Small-Bench-Power-Supply/) tutorial has exactly the same thing I am looking for but he is using different converter circuit.